# getWidth not working correctly as class variable

Tags: java, class, variables, inner-classes, acm.graphics

I am very new to java (and programming in general) and I trying to make a program that simply draws a vertical line down the centre of the screen. To do this, I made a variable `x` which gives me the x coordinate of the centre of the screen. I wanted to be able to use this variable within other private methods. When I run the code however, no line appears, as if `x` were set to 0.

```
import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Target extends GraphicsProgram {   
    int x = getWidth()/2;
    public void run() {
        GLine line = new GLine (x,0,x,300);
        add (line);
    }
}
```

If I put my variable `x` inside the `run()` method as below, the line is drawn correctly, but then I would not be able to use it later in other private methods as it is my understanding that then the variable would no longer be class variable but an instance variable and therefor only accessible by `run()` and no other methods?

```
public class Target extends GraphicsProgram {   
   public void run() {
        int x = getWidth()/2;            
        GLine line = new GLine (x,0,x,300);
        add (line);
    }
}
```

Could someone enlighten me as to why the first code does not work whereas the second one does?
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I believe this has to do with the lifecycle of the graphics. The width must be set after the instance initializer is ran.

Comment: @ Sotirios Delimanolis Thank you for your answer but I don't think I quite understand. If by 'lifecycle' you mean that the graphics sort of 'expire' after a while (please correct me if I assume wrong and please excuse my layman language), why can't the current value of getWidth() be assigned to x and be done with? Thank you though for your speedy reply!

Comment: As zjor has replied below, the GUI API has to instantiate your class before it can assign any values to its fields. `getWidth()` in an instance field initialization expression will run before the GUI framework can do anything, ie. won't be able to set the width yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first version `getWidth()` is called during instance initialisation and bounds of your window probably has not been set yet. So it still works but the method returns 0 and you probably don't see the line on the screen.

Comment: Right, thanks to yourself and @ Sotirios Delimanolis I think I now understand the problem. To fix this, I first declared `x` within the class, and then later assigned `getWidth()/2` in the `run()` instance.